# Can't fetch data from Firestore with React search bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to make a simple search bar to fetch some data from the Cloud Firestore database. Can you help me? I'm new to React and it still costs me a lot. I use version 9 modular of firebase

This is my code taken from a tutorial.

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react"
import { db } from "../firebase/firebase"

export default function Search(){
    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const [filteredContacts, setFilteredContacts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const data = await db.collection("users").orderBy("name").get();
          setContacts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        };
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setFilteredContacts(
          contacts.filter(
            (user) =>
              user.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
              user.city.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
          )
        );
      }, [search, contacts]);


    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-lg-12">
<>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Contact Details</h1>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {filteredContacts.map((user) => [
          <ol>
            <b>Consumer Details :</b> {<br />}
            {user.name},{<br />}
            {user.company},{<br />}
            {user.city},{<br />}
            {user.contact},{<br />}
          </ol>,
        ])}
      </div>
    </>                </div>
           

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I hope you can help me, I know that the code that I implement is from firebase 8, but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: What is the particular issue that you are encoutering? Are you able to provide what you have tried, what you expect, and what happens?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering, the main problem is the following: WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.db.collection is not a function, and it is because that is firebase 8 syntax, but, I don't know how to modify the same code for firebase 9 :(

Comment: Firebase provides documentation for migration, take a look here for an example specific to Firestore:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#example_2_refactoring_a_function

Comment: This specific error also has come up a few times, and you can get the most relevant results by limiting the search to the past year: https://www.google.com/search?q=db.collection+is+not+a+function+firestore&sxsrf=ALiCzsaCVNCSaw7bjX1Ksa4e9BhAoPhS9g:1660335564561&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSjqL8j8L5AhVnLkQIHdcaDfwQpwV6BAgBEBo&biw=1189&bih=984&dpr=2